Can't print to console in Godot 4 C#
I create a new project, add a root Node2D called 'Level' and attach a script:
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class Level : Node2D
{
    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }

    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
    }
}

After running the game, nothing appears in the output:
screenshot of output (I do have all the output types enabled)
When I try throwing an exception from the function:
public override void _Ready()
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
    throw new Exception("test");
}

Then we do see the error.
sc of output
What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

using static Godot.GD;

public class Test
{
    static Test()
    {
        Print("Hello"); // Instead of GD.Print("Hello");
    }
}

